# LaTeX pdf compilation problem after installation

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, texmaker

After installing Texmaker and Miktex I cannot successfully compile a pdf file.

After clicking on Quick Build, I get a message in Message/Log window "Process started" and it never ends. During the process of compilation, I can click "View pdf", but the pdf is not updated.

In addition to that, even after I close the program, it is still loaded into CPU memory.

Configuration of my Texmaker looks in the following way:
[image: Commands]
[image: Quick Build]

So where is the problem?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem might be that your input file contains an error that causes LaTeX to hang. Could you try compiling `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello World\end{document}` and see if it results in the same issue?

Comment: @Marijn Yes! You are right! Thank you!

Comment: So does this mean that the issue is solved? If yes, then we can close the question.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, we can close question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by a problem in the input file.